# UDP Socket Set Timeout

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to set a 100ms timeout on a UDP Socket.  I am using C.  I have posted relavent pieces of my code below.  I am not sure why this is not timing out, but just hangs when it doesn't receive a segment.  Does this only work on sockets that are not bound using the bind() method?

```
#define TIMEOUT_MS      100     /* Seconds between retransmits */

if ((rcv_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
    DieWithError("socket() failed");

if ((rcv_sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) < 0)
    DieWithError("socket() failed");

//set timer for recv_socket
static int timeout = TIMEOUT_MS;
setsockopt(rcv_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,(char*)&timeout,sizeof(timeout));

if(recvfrom(rcv_sock, ackBuffer,sizeof(ackBuffer), 0,
       (struct sockaddr *) &servAddr2, &fromSize) < 0){
    //timeout reached
    printf("Timout reached. Resending segment %d\n", seq_num);
    num_timeouts++;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are not checking the return value from `setsockopt` to see if it returned an error. It probably is. `SO_RCVTIMEO` is documented on both Linux and MacOS to take a `struct timeval`, but you are passing an `int`. Try passing a `struct timeval` instead. Also, why are you casting `&timeout` to `char *`? It's not a `char *` at all.

Comment: @Celada on Windows, setsockopt() takes a 'char*' as the 2nd argument for any of the options.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The `SO_RCVTIMEO` option expects a `struct timeval` defined in `sys/time.h`, not an integer like you're passing to it. The `timeval struct` has as field for seconds and a field for microseconds. To set the timeout to 100ms, the following should do the trick:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 100000;
if (setsockopt(rcv_sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO,&tv,sizeof(tv)) < 0) {
    perror("Error");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. I tried to adopt the solution you suggested, using the `timeval` struct. But it did not seem to work.

I have read on the Microsoft documentation and the time should be a `DWORD` with the number of milliseconds, but there is also another thing to do, If the socket is created using the `WSASocket` function, then the `dwFlags` parameter must have the `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` attribute set for the timeout to function properly.
 Otherwise the timeout never takes effect.

Comment: The accepted answer targets POSIX sockets. Windows provides its own socket API so the accepted answer is not applicable to Windows.