# UDP socket select() returns 1 without delay (timeout) under some conditions

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, winsock2

I fallen into problem during development of my client application.

I want to use non-blocking UDP sockets in my application to communicate with a server. I am using `winsock2` library on Windows.

But... For some reason I have strange behavior of `select()` function under some conditions:

1. Socket don't have bound address and port (it is client-side socket, so it don't need it).
2. Before `select()` I send data to my **local** address and some port with `sendto` call.

   - For example: `192.168.1.2`

Under these conditions `select()` instantly (**without even waiting for timeout**) returns `1`. Like I have some packet ready to receive.
But if call `recvFrom` then it will sure return `-1`.

---

1. If I send my packets from client to any other address (which is not my address on LAN) then `select()` works as intended.
2. Also `select()` works as intented if don't send any packets to any address before calling `select()`.

---

Socket initialization method:

```
bool CUdpSocket::initialize()
{
  _handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

  ... error processing code, returns false if error...
}
```

---

Method which uses `select()`. This method works fine for server socket (with bound address and port).

```
bool CUdpSocket::waitData(s32 timeout_ms)
{
    fd_set readset;
    int result;
    struct timeval tv;

    // Initialize the set.
    FD_ZERO(&readset);
    FD_SET(_handle, &readset);

    // Initialize time out struct.
    tv.tv_sec = 0;
    tv.tv_usec = timeout_ms * 1000;

    result = select(_handle + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);

    // Timeout with no data.
    if (result == 0) {
        return false; // Get out of here!
    }

    // Error.
    if (result < 0) {
        // TODO: Maybe throw exception or do something.
        return false;
    } else if (!FD_ISSET(_handle, &readset)) {
        return false; // No data!
    }

    // There is some data!
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547721/udp-socket-set-timeout, http://danzig.jct.ac.il/tcp-ip-lab/inet-dgram/timeout/

Comment: `recvfrom()` will return -1 with what error?

Comment: @EJP Hmmm... Forgot to check that. WSAGetLastError after ``recvFrom`` call returns code 10054 (WSAECONNRESET).

Comment: Google is your friend: Google "WSAECONNRESET UDP" - top hit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749423/is-winsock-error-10054-wsaeconnreset-normal-with-udp-to-from-localhost, as per comment by  @ChrisDodd below.  I hope you learned something about digging into your own problems from this.

Answer (score 0):

If you send a packet from an unbound UDP socket, the OS will pick an usused port for you and bind the socket to that port -- the UDP protocol *requires* that the sending port have an address to send from.

So if the packet you're sending results in a response, then it makes perfect sense for the select to return 1 -- that's the response to the packet you sent.

Comment: As I wrote. Problem is... I am constantly getting returm `1` even if server application is not started (there is no response). And the ``select()`` returns `1` instantly. Without waiting when timeout expire. This happen only if address where I send request address is my LAN address.

Comment: If the server is not running, you may be getting an ICMP error response from the the OS.  In which case, that may show up as an error on the receiving socket.